# What is the best way to retrieve the most recent row in a table that contains a specific value in a specific column in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

Say I have a table with five rows. The information in each row is mostly irrelevant to me aside from the information in one column, COL_CHAR:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       COL_ID        |     COL_NAME     |     COL_CHAR     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         01          |     Name 01      |         X        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         02          |     Name 02      |         Y        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         03          |     Name 03      |         Z        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         04          |     Name 04      |         X        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         05          |     Name 05      |         Y        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to retrieve information from the row where COL_CHAR contains the bottom-most/most recent X - in this case, the fourth row. In the context of what I'm working on, X represents the most recent occurrence of a specific action performed by the application, and it's important for the row the most recent X belongs to to be used to retrieve other information.

To simplify further, I want to find the most recently-added row where the value of COL_CHAR is "X", then retrieve the value of COL_NAME from the same row.

All of the relevant code I've written is in Kotlin, but I can understand Java code fine, if that's easier.

Comment: If you have an SQLiteOpenHelper class for the database and table you are working on you should post it to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where col_char = 'X'
order by col_id desc limit 1
```